# Whats wrong with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

i have this code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^/pages/(.*)$ ^/pages?url=$1$
```

When user on `site.com/pages/test-name` server must get is as `site.com/pages?url=myurl`
what is my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^pages/(.+)$ /pages.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```